# Can someone help explain this code? It is a shell script for creating a checksum list

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
# create a list of checksums
cat /dev/null > MD5SUM
for i in */*/*.sql ; do test -e $i && md5sum $i >>MD5SUM ; done
```

Then this command is used to check to see if anything has changed:

```
md5sum -c MD5SUM
```

It works fine and everything. I just don't really understand how. Say if I wanted to make a checksum list of all the files in my home directory `$HOME` how can I do that? What  does the `*/*/*.sql` part of the for loop mean? I'm assuming that is to display SQL files only but how can I modify that? Say I wanted all files in the directory? Why is it not just `*.sql` ? What does the rest of the for loop do in this case?

Comment: Can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Lets go by parts:

```
cat /dev/null > MD5SUM
```

this will only "erase" the previous MD5SUM file/list that was created before.

```
for i in */*/*.sql;
```

this will iterate over files that are 2 directories deep from your current folder. If you have folders

```
~/a/b
~/c/d
~/e/f
```

and you run your script in your home folder (~) all "*.sql" inside directories b,d,f will have the checksum calculated and piped to a file MD5SUM in the current direcotry:

```
do test -e $i && md5sum $i >>MD5SUM ; done
```

Now Answering your questions:

> 1. Say if I wanted to make a checksum list of all the files in my home directory $HOME how can I do that?

I would use the find command with the exec option

```
find $HOME -maxdepth 1 -name \*.sql -exec md5sum {} \;
```

> 1. What does the */*/*.sql part of the for loop mean?

I answered it above, anyway only goes 2 directories deep before getting to the files.

> 1. I'm assuming that is to display SQL files only but how can I modify that? Say I wanted all files in the directory?

Change

```
for i in */*/*.sql;
```

to

```
for i in */*/*;
```

or for current directory

```
find $HOME -maxdepth 1 -name \* -exec md5sum {} \;
```

> 1. Why is it not just *.sql ? What does the rest of the for loop do in this case?

Explained before.

Hope it helps =)